# NodeJS ReactJS Redux displays undefined for token api token

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, jwt

I am using NodeJS ReactJS Redux with JWT in an application and I have issue getting expiresIn and token at the reactjs frontend. When I console log the token at the NodeJS controller, it displays the token nd everything perfectly but it pointed to the jwt.verify() with error `JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed` but at the ReactJS frontend, it displays the payLoad userData part of the token and displays undefined for both expiresIn and token.

As you can see in the Redux authSlice class that I set localStorage Item in there for token, expire and userData but when I tried to get the localStorage item in another page, I could only get the userData payloads but the token and expire are undefined.

I don't know what is wrong here because the NodeJS sent the token for real as I can get the token from console of NodeJS and ThunderClient API as well gave an 200 OK when i test the api using ThunderClient in VS Code.

My concern is that ThunderClient displays 200 OK and return Token, expiresIn and userData complete and everything perfect, NodeJS console displays correct information on console but gave `JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed` and at ReactJS frontend, I got the userData from the token sent by the API but accessToken and expiresIn are missing i.e out of the 3 string that JWT encrypted, I got only the Payload which is the userData.

How can I solve this?

*******************NODEJS

jwtHelper.js

```
exports.extractToken = (req) => {
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
        return req.query.token;
    }
    return null;
}
```

jwtVerify.js

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        const token = extractToken(req);

        if (token == null) {
            return res.status(StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED).send("Unauthorized");
        }
        
        jwt.verify(token, common_helper.getJWTAccessToken(), {}, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN).send("Invalid user");
            }
            req.user = user["userData"];
            next();
        });
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
};
```

Login (Controller)

```
const token = jwt.sign({userData}, common_helper.getJWTAccessToken(), {
          algorithm: 'HS256',
          expiresIn: common_helper.getJWTExpiryTime(),
   });

res.status(StatusCodes.OK).send({"expires_in": common_helper.getJWTExpiryTime(),"access_token":token,"token_type": "bearer","userData":userData});

console.log(`The token is ${token}`) // This displays the ciper token
console.log(`The secret_token is ${common_helper.getJWTExpiryTime()}`) //this displays the real secret key
```

*******************REACTJS

Redux Slice. Note that the localStorage is set here

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface IAuthToken {
    isAuthenticated?:boolean,
    jwtToken: any;
    expiryDate: any;
    errorMessage?:string;
    userData?:any;
    notverified?: string;
}

const initialState: IAuthToken = {
    jwtToken: undefined,
    expiryDate: undefined,
    errorMessage:'',
    isAuthenticated:false,
    userData:undefined,
    notverified: undefined,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setJWTToken: (state, _action: PayloadAction<IAuthToken>) => {
            state.jwtToken = _action.payload.jwtToken;
            state.expiryDate = _action.payload.expiryDate;
            state.userData=_action.payload.userData;
            localStorage.setItem('token', state.jwtToken);
            //localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(state.jwtToken));
            localStorage.setItem('expire', state.expiryDate);
            //localStorage.setItem('expire', JSON.stringify(state.expiryDate));
            if(state.userData)
            localStorage.setItem('userData',JSON.stringify(state.userData));
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.notverified = _action.payload.notverified;
           
        },
        removeJWTToken: (state) => {
            localStorage.clear();
            state.jwtToken = '';
            state.expiryDate=undefined;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
        },
        setError: (state, _action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
            state.errorMessage = _action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export const { setJWTToken, removeJWTToken,setError } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

ReactJS Login

```
Axios.post(`${baseURL}/signin`, { username: formik.values.username,  password: formik.values.password})
            .then((response) => {
              if(response.data.notverified)
              {
                setSubmitting("");
                navigate("/needemailconfirmation", { replace: true });                
              }
                           
                setSubmitting("");               
                console.log(response.data)
                dispatch(setJWTToken(response.data));                                            
                navigate("/dashboardd", { replace: true });
```

authAction

```
export const signIn = (email, password) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .post(`${url}/signin`, { email, password })
      .then((token) => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", token.data);

        dispatch({
          type: "SIGN_IN",
          token: token.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);

        toast.error(error.response?.data, {
          position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        });
      });
  };
};
```

authReducer

```
const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SIGN_IN":
    case "SIGN_UP":
    case "USER_LOADED":
      toast("Welcome...", {
        position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
      });
      const user = jwtDecode(action.token); 
      return {
        ...initialState,
        token: action.token,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        _id: user._id,
      };
    case "SIGN_OUT":
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      toast("Goodbye...", {
        position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
      });
      return {
        token: null,
        name: null,
        email: null,
        _id: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

In my ReactJS frontend, from the token sent by the NodeJS api I was able to get userData payload from the token but I could not get the token and expiresIn for reason I do not know.

[You can find the token details from the browser inspect here where I got userData payload but got undefines for accesstoken and expiresIn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXwwu.png)

### Update

In my question above, I made the point of not getting the token value in my ReactJS frontendm while debugging the code I set the localStorage at the login page immediately after a successful login and i used the localStorage getItem() to get the value in my Redux slice but the issue that persist is that my ReactJS frontend is not allowing me to get to dashboard as it is acting like the value is not set i.e the middleware cannot get the value at the and the route allow the user to navigate to the dashboard is bouncing the navigation back to login page despite the fact that the token is set and I can get the token at the browser inspect to be sure that it is set but Auth Middleware is not getting it. See the code I have now below:

******************ReactJS

Login.js

```
   //call the api
        Axios.post(`${baseURL}/signin`, { username: formik.values.username,  password: formik.values.password})
            .then((response) => {
              if(response.data.notverified)
              {
                setSubmitting("");
                navigate("/needemailconfirmation", { replace: true });                
              }
                           
                setSubmitting("");                
                console.log(response.data)
                if(response.data.access_token){
                  dispatch(setJWTToken(response.data));  
                  localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.data.access_token));
          
                  localStorage.setItem('expire', JSON.stringify(response.data.expires_in));  
                           
                  localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(response.data.userData));                            
                }
            
                navigate("/dashboardd", { replace: true });             
      
      }) .catch((error) =>{
        setSubmitting("");
          //console.log(error.data);
          setErrorMsg("Invalid Login Credentials Supplied.");
          //alert("Invalid Login Credentials Supplied, Error : <br>" + error.data);
      });
      }
```

Redux Slice Auth File

```
interface IAuthToken {
    isAuthenticated?:boolean,
    jwtToken: any;
    expiryDate: any;
    errorMessage?:string;
    userData?:any;
    notverified?: string;
}

const initialState: IAuthToken = {
    jwtToken: undefined,
    expiryDate: undefined,
    errorMessage:'',
    isAuthenticated:false,
    userData:undefined,
    notverified: undefined,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setJWTToken: (state, _action: PayloadAction<IAuthToken>) => {                   state.jwtToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
            state.expiryDate = localStorage.getItem("expire");
            state.userData = localStorage.getItem("userData");
           
            if(localStorage.getItem("userData"))           
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.notverified = '';
           
        },
        removeJWTToken: (state) => {
            localStorage.clear();
            state.jwtToken = '';
            state.expiryDate=undefined;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
        },
        setError: (state, _action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
            state.errorMessage = _action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export const { setJWTToken, removeJWTToken,setError } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

AuthenticatedRoute.js : this is used in bouncing user back if they token is not found

```
const AuthenticatedRoute: FC<{ element: any }> = ({ element }) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const expire = localStorage.getItem('expire');
    
    const now = Date.now();
    if (token && expire && parseInt(expire) > parseInt(now.toString())) {
        return element;
    } else {
        return <Navigate to="/" replace />
    }
};

export default AuthenticatedRoute;
```

My React Router Dom

```
<Route path="/checkpoint" element={<AuthenticatedRoute element={<CheckpointList />} />}></Route>

<Route path="/vendour" element={<AuthenticatedRoute element={<VendourList />} />}></Route>
```

React Router Dom path are working normal but just that if I put AuthenticatedRoute to dashboard Route, it would not allow me in because the AuthenticatedRoute is not seeing the token I think but when I console the token in dashboard if i remove AuthenticatedRoute, the values are there.

Using React Router Dom, I was debugging this code and remove the AuthenticatedRoute middleware from dashboard and I was able to navigate to dashboard and get the localStorage value for the token and expiresIn but the point remains that when I put the AuthenticatedRoute middleware in the dashboad Route, the AuthenticatedRoute would bounce me back to login page meaning it cannot find the token.